azuredevops pipeline retryCountOnTaskFailure doesn't exist
in my azuredevops pipeliene, when try to add retryCountOnTaskFailure to any task i got the below message

Unexpected value 'retryCountOnTaskFailure', even when try to use autocomplete the feature is not found


Version Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2
Agent version 2.181.2

I expect to get info about this feature requirements

Can you share a snippet of the workflow you're working on? Which task are you adding to, what agent or agentless config in your job definition?

As per Automatic retries for a task (Azure Pipelines - Sprint 195 Update of November 16, 2021):

Requires agent version 2.194.0 or later. Not supported for agentless tasks.

Given that you're using build agent v2.181.2, you must upgrade your build agents in order to use the retryCountOnTaskFailure property.
